# Asterisk Manager Api events

Tags: voip, asterisk, asteriskami

I am using Elastix along with the Astmanproxy server to run our call center desktop app. This app gathers info such as callerid, number dialed, etc. to help our agents get customer information among other things. This app changes it's background color upon certain events(like green when the agent answers the call).

I use the Dial event in the AMI to grab the call's unique id (I use the DestUniqueID variable to get this id). After that I track all events with that unique id. When I get a Link event with that id that app's background turns green indicating that call center agent has answered the call.

The problem is, even though the agent answers the call, sometimes I do not get a Link event with the matching unique id that I get from the DestUniqueID of the Dial event. Does anyone know why this happens?

Basically, is there a fool-proof way to track a call from beginning to end using the asterisk manager api events?

Comment: Basically, is there a fool-proof way to track a call from beginning to end using the asterisk manager api events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you monitor all the events then you should be able to trace the call including the dialplans.

Answer (score 0):

Try catch a NewStateEvent when the call get answered. It has old and new unique id.